# Trying to get linux command to work in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm trying to run this Ruby Script I made on a Linux server...  However, I'm having some issues understanding why it's failing.  I thought this syntax would just be able to execute my command properly...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

```rb
#!/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
system("find . -size +20G -exec ls -l {} \;")
```

Script output -
find: missing argument to `-exec' (edited)

```rb
#!/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
system("find . -size +20G -exec ls -l {} \;")
```

Script output -
find: missing argument to `-exec' (edited)

Comment: Does the argument to system work outside of ruby? I suspect it is broken there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
system('find . -size +20G -exec ls -l {} \;')
```

or double the backslash:

```
system("find . -size +20G -exec ls -l {} \\;")
```

or single quote the escaped semicolon:

```
system("find . -size +20G -exec ls -l {} '\;'")
```

or separate the arguments (thanks to @tadman):

```
system('find', '.', '-size', '+20G', '-exec', 'ls', '-l' ,'{}', ';')
```

or do that but start with a string:

```
system(*"find . -size +20G -exec ls -l {} ;".split)
```

or here that is with a variable holding the string:

```
cmd = "find . -size +20G -exec ls -l {} ;"
system(*cmd.split)
```

These last two split the string into an array then the `*` turns the array into a list of arguments.

Ruby thinks you're escaping the semicolon and you need to prevent that by escaping the backslash because `find` needs the semicolon and since it's a shell special character it needs to be escaped. Hence, double escaping.

Or do it directly in Ruby:

```ruby
require 'find'
Find.find(".") do |path|
  if FileTest.size(path) > 20 * 2 ** 9
    puts path
  end
end
```

You can add additional tests such as whether an entry is a directory and output additional information about the file.

Comment: Even better, use discrete arguments: `system('find', '.', '-size', '+20G', '-exec', 'ls', '-l' ,'{}', %q['\;'])`

Comment: @tadman: Or even better, do it in Ruby (answer edited). By the way, I get a "missing argument to `-exec` using your suggestion, But if I change the last argument to `';'` (no escaping at all) it works.

Comment: That's even-even better, nice!

Comment: Dude, you guys rock!  This is like cheat codes!  Thank you!!!  I'll be back to help contribute when I master ruby!

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Wait... you're saying I can run use Ruby and run Real Ruby commands on a linux system?

Comment: @ZMan007 ruby is a scripting language so yeahhhh!